# Why isn't This Pagination Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to paginate a list of images Which are pulled from a directory on my site. I have been successful where as the "One, two, three..sixteen" text in the div  paginates. However all the images ( around 50)all  load at the same time and skip the pagination.

Is this a loading order with my Scripts or do I need to reconsider how I'm pulling the images from another directory?

Im using this Pagination plugin  - http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/

**JQUERY SCRIPTS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    $.ajax({
        url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
        success: function(data){
            var imageNames = [];
            $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
                // store each image name into array
                imageNames.push($(this).attr("href"));
               });

            var sortedImageNames = imageNames.sort();

            for(var i = sortedImageNames.length; i-- > 0;) {
                    var linkImage = 'user-uploads/' + sortedImageNames[i];
                    var thumbnailImage = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + sortedImageNames[i];
                    var item = '<li><a class="fancybox" href="' 
                        + linkImage 
                        + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class=dropshadow src="' 
                        + thumbnailImage 
                        + '"></a></li>';
                    $(item).appendTo('.alt_content');
                }
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#paging_container3').pajinate({
                    items_per_page : 5,
                    item_container_id : '.alt_content',
                    nav_panel_id : '.alt_page_navigation'   
                })

</script>
```

**DIV Im Trying TO PAGINATE**

```
        <div id="paging_container3" class="container">
            <h2>Custom List Size</h2>
            <div class="alt_page_navigation"></div>
            <ul class="alt_content">
                 <li><p>One</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Two</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Three</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Four</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Five</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Six</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Seven</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Eight</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Nine</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Ten</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Eleven</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Twelve</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Thirteen</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Fourteen</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Fifteen</p></li> 
                 <li><p>Sixteen</p></li> 
            </ul>   
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but should you not have `;` at the end of `pajinate function`?

Comment: thanks for the help, but that was just an error when i was pasting the code over.

Answer (score 0):

Put your 
 `$('#paging_container3').pajinate();` 
function inside the `$(document).ready();` function.

The pajinate code is executing before the `#paging_container3` is loaded I believe.